# Having Issue with file name appended with date -shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to append the current day and time to the existing file name in shell scripting and I found my command is not working as expected.

For example, if my file name is f1.log and I nees to append it along with current time. This appended version must be used for further processing of the file.

I tried with the following script but getting an error

```
    now=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y/%T")
    echo hi >>time.log
    mv "time.log" "time.$now.log" (error here : file or directory not found)
    echo hello >> time.log$now   (have to continue processing with new file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with shell's interpertation of `/` in your `date +"%m-%d-%Y/%T"`.

Change it to a `-` instead (or something else, as long as it's not `/` or another meta character that will make the files difficult to work with in the future)

Comment: `/` is not a meta-character to the shell.  The problem is that it is the delimiter between directory names in the path.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a `/` character in a filename.  The `mv` command is looking for a directory named with the minute, day, and year of the output of date and trying to create a file named by the time.  Just change your format to not include `/` in the filename.

Comment: oops! yeah I failed to realize that. Thanks !